# Poor image quality in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, image, listview

I'm populating a ListView with items and add images from an ImageList (in the designer). The images, however, are displayed in very poor quality, even though I've set the image size in the ImageList to their original size (16x16). Have a look:

[Terrible image quality http://balazsbotond.hu/downloads/listview-icons.png](http://balazsbotond.hu/downloads/listview-icons.png)

The original images are beautiful, sharp PNG icons. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this was pretty easy. Just don't change the image size of the ImageList after adding the images :)

Answer (score 12):

Try this line of code.

```
ImageList1.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth16Bit;
```

Answer (score 4):

change the colordepth of your imagesList that you're using for the listview and try a higher colorDepth depending on the PNGs (like Depth32Bit) and  you'll see the diffrence .

Answer (score 0):

For higher quality of image, we have to use the higher ColorDepth for **ImageList**.
The higher Depth allowed in C# is **Depth32Bit**

Sample usage is as given below

```
imgLstPhotos.ColorDepth = ColorDepth.Depth32Bit;
```

**Reference Screenshot:**

[image]